# Add SubView in Landscape mode in Portrait only app

Tags: iphone, ios6, orientation

My app is a Portrait only app. I need to add a sub view in Landscape mode. For the new view to be added, I have set the below orientation in iOS 6.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger options = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if (self.inAppBrowserOrientation)
     {
        if (self.inAppBrowserOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.inAppBrowserOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        options = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        return options;
    }
}
```

The view will be added in Portrait mode. On orientation this view will be rotating only in Landscape mode, which is as expected.

For the first time upon adding the view, why it adds in Portrait mode? while the `self.inAppBrowserOrientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

Comment: Try with else part also.Write return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; in else part also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(270));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 480, 44.0);


} 

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];   

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 480);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0);

}
```

Here,Default Orientation is Portrait but when compiler go to viewDidAppear it will rotate 270 degree hence in landscape mode..
Adjust your frame size accordingly...

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following snippet

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger options = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    if (self.inAppBrowserOrientation)
     {
        if (self.inAppBrowserOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.inAppBrowserOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        options = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        return options;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
```

}

I'm not sure but probably this could be problem when you load aqpp for the first time

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: Still the view is added as portrait. As self.inAppBrowserOrientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, only UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape will be returned each time.

Comment: did you check with debug point?? when view is loaded for the first time,, after viewWillAppear what happens within supportedInterfaceOrientations??

Comment: po self.inAppBrowserOrientation
$0 = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight [no Objective-C description available]

Comment: try to add this line [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; in viewDidLoad method for your view, if done apply this for every screen with bith supported orientation